# How to check if the class is added to div element using react or javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to close the list menu if a user clicks anywhere outside the list menu. This means that when clicking anywhere on the document except the list, the list menu should be closed.

To do that, I have the method defined like below (react),

```
handle_click = (event) => {
    if (this.list_menu_ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        return;
    }
    this.props.on_close(); //this method handles closing the list menu
};
```

This works fine. now I have an overlay sometimes when this is active and list menu opens and also when a user clicks anywhere on the document, I don't want the list menu to close in that case.

from the domnode we can identify this overlay with the class active is visible like below,

```
<div id="overlay_root" class="active>
    //some content
</div>
```

So whenever this active class gets added to the div with id "overlay_root" and a user clicks on the document I don't want the list menu to close.

How can I do it? could someone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to check if the class is added to div element using react or
>   javascript?

That's a way to check if element contains a class and remove it

```
if ( document.getElementById("overlay_root").classList.contains('active') ){
  document.getElementById("overlay_root").classList.remove('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have two class

> active : for showing list

and

> de-active : for hiding list

and here is your list

```
<div id="overlay_root" class="active" onClick = {e => yourMethod(e)}>
    //some content
</div>
```

and your method is like

```
   yourMethod = (e)=>{
       this.setState(listMenuToggle : !this.state.listMenuToggle )
    }
```

here you can see you have a state called **listMenuToggle**, it may contains **true** or **false**. when it's true you will show your list and for false close the list. so your list will be somethings like

```
<div id="overlay_root" class={this.state.listMenuToggle ? 'active' : 'de-active' } onClick = {e => yourMethod(e)}>
    //some content
</div>
```